# C++ Use derived class method to change base class data member

Tags: c++

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to access and change base class data member using derived class method.
Following code is a sample of what I want to do.

```
class A
{
    protected:
        string name;
    public:
        A():name("Name 1"){}
        void DisplayA()
        {
            cout<<name<<endl;
        }
};
class B : public A
{
    public:
        void Change()
        {
            cout<<"Enter New Name: ";
            getline(cin,name);
        }
        void DisplayB()
        {
            cout<<name<<endl;
        }
};
main()
{
    A Obj1;
    B Obj2;
    Obj1.DisplayA();
    Obj2.Change();   // I want this method to change the name in Base class too.
    Obj2.DisplayB(); 
    Obj1.DisplayA(); // This method should now display the new name that we set in Change();
}
```

Comment: You can do this if to declare the data member as a static data member of the base class.

Comment: There is no relation between `Obj1`, and `Obj2`, so non-static data members of one can't really be changed by the other.

Comment: Both classes have their own `name` member, so the `DisplayB()` function is redundant. If you want a data member that is shared in-between all instances of classes A and B, you'll have to use `static string name`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks! Completely forgot about static eh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define name as `static std::string` because modifying non-static members of an object change them only for that object.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I forgot this.